# how can I make a selectable list?

Tags: package, helm-selection

I'm working on a package and I want to present a list to the users that they can select from.

The package allows editing of remote Dokuwiki pages from Emacs which can be found here: https://github.com/accidentalrebel/emacs-dokuwiki

I want to list pages that users can scroll up and down, once they press enter it should open the page they have selected. I'm thinking this can be done by listing the selection in a new buffer, then just code it in a way it can only accept up, down, and enter commands.

Are there other alternatives to doing this? I can use helm too but want to know if there are other simpler options.

Comment: It doesn't get any simpler than `completing-read`.

Comment: It's best to use `completing-read`. That will be translated to more advanced UI if user has installed ivy or helm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already referred by comments, `completing-read` is the way to go.

For example, the code below may give you some insight, also includes helm/counsel integration below.

- https://github.com/lurdan/moomin-el/blob/lurdan/counsel-support/moomin.el#L323

Comment: Thank you to everyone for showing me completing-read.

The sample code is also immensely helpful!

Comment: Please show an example or describe the solution. Otherwise this is almost a link-only answer.